# Is "coworkers" correct and natural?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

**When it was my birthday I made a big cake for all my coworkers.**

I'm at the bottom of a big company. There is a lot of different functions in the company, though most of the employees work at a computer. If I'm referring to everyone at the company, is it correct and natural to use "coworkers"?

When I search on Google there is way more hits for "for all my colleagues" than "for all my coworkers".

Answer (score 3):

"Coworkers" is okay, but it tends to suggest people who are at a comparable level with you. So if you are a programmer at Microsoft, your coworkers might include other programmers, and perhaps other "office workers".  But you probably wouldn't include Bill Gates as a coworker, or people who work in different locations. Then again, if you brought in a cake for your birthday, I think you'd be rather surprised if Bill Gates put his head round the door to have a slice.  So "coworkers" is fine in your context.

The word colleague is also possible, and it may be better.

Comment: The word colleague is more like all the people with your line of interest in work. Could be from another company or bussiness. However the Coworkers directly refers to the people in your work space.

Comment: No, "colleagues" means "people in the same company" or someone who, from the perspective of a customer, seems to be in the same company.

Comment: It does seem like "colleagues" and "coworkers" both fall short of the "Bill Gates benchmark" here. I think referencing employees and "for the office" would similarly fall short. "For everyone at the company" is less concise but would more aptly include the entire hierarchy.

Comment: @JamesK I happen to disagree with you! Colleagues does not always meant to be the same company forexample, ***Working for AB has given me the chance to
interact with colleagues from all over the world.*** It is the people in same line of work.

Comment: Fair enough.  I find that a very odd use, perhaps a dialect difference that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @JamesK it is certainly rare so understandable but in general offcourse it is used as a wide version of co-workers. So you are right too.

Answer (score 3):

“coworkers” implies the people that you work with, hence “co-“.

“colleague” could refer to anyone in a similar position or field (“league”), even if you have limited or no interaction with them.

If the cake is intended primarily for your friends at your office, I would use “coworkers”.